# How to fix gsm modem LTE connection lacking download?

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, usb, usb-modem

I've recently bought `ZTE MF820D` USB GSM modem especially for the `LTE` feature, although that's the only mode I'm having problem with. `EDGE` and `UMTS` are working fine, but after a while the mode is changed to `LTE` and download stops completely, while uploading continues. When I establish a new `LTE` connection, every time I see 62 bits sent and no more, and again upload rising.

There was a one (ONE!) `LTE` connection that worked, and that was exactly after system update and reboot. Never before or later...

**How can I debug that? Any useful tips for `system logs`?**

Again, `Modem Manager GUI` and `system bar networks` are saying that the connection is negotiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to do a **firmware update** of  the `ZTE MF820D` GSM modem under Windows, found [HERE](https://netcom.no/kundeservice/mobiltbredband/zte-mf820d).

Previous version: B14
New version: B33